# Access attribute from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a Customer and Invoice Model. A customer has many invoices and an invoice belongs_to a customer.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :billing_address, :customer_currency, :email, :first_name, :last_name,    :mobile, :name, :payment_terms, :phase_type, :pays_vat
 validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :mobile, :billing_address, :payment_terms,  :phase_type, :customer_currency

has_many :invoices

validates :email, 
        :presence => true,
        :uniqueness => true, 
        :email_format => true

validates :name, :mobile, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Invoice Model is

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer
attr_accessible :approved_by, :due_date, :invoice_date, :terms, :customer_id, :customer

validates :invoice_date, presence: true
validates :due_date, presence: true
validates :customer, presence: true
```

I am trying to create an index page that lists all the invoices in the system and this will invoice showing a customer Name to whom the invoice belongs. How can i retrieve that and clearly depict it in my model and view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've already created customer and invoice controllers and views (if not do it by `generate scaffold`). Then list invoices in **views\invoices\index.html.erb**:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Invoice</th>
    <th>Customer/th>
  </tr>
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= invoice.num %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.customer.first_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Of course, you should declare `@invoices` in **controllers/invoices_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.includes(:customer).all
end
```

Comment: You should probably use Invoice.includes(:customer).all to avoid additional queries while iterating over the invoices.

Comment: It sure will, but if there are 10 invoices, you will have to make 11 sql queries - get all of the invoices and 1 for each invoice (fetching customer's first_name). If you use the `includes` method, you have just 2 queries to make.

Comment: Good notice, thank you. But it will generate the query with `in` where condition, which is not very quick. Did you make any experiments that says that 'includes' method always better?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about IN's performance. The main point is that without the `includes` call, the number of sql queries would grow with the number of invoices (N+1). With `includes`, you would still have just 2.

Comment: Thanks for this input, it is actually working, now going to try with the includes

Comment: Jiri, I think you're right, thx for the feedback! I've edited the answer.

Comment: How about a situation where an invoice has many invoice_items and I want to include the amount, an invoice item in my invoices index page.`class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :invoice_items end` and my controller has `def index
  @invoices = Invoice.includes(:customer, :invoice_items).all
end` `class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :rate, :tax_amount
end`
How can I show amount in invoice index? @alex

Comment: You have `amount` attribute (field), so just use it as in my view code, but instead of `<%= invoice.num %>` use `<%= invoice.amount %>`